# Consume ASMX from MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asmx

I have a legacy asmx service (which I have never worked with them). I want to consume it from an MVC application.

First I Add Service Reference with the following wsdl http://thisisanexample.com:1928/WSTest/Service.asmx?wsdl.
The service generated some classes:

- Request and Response classes for each method
- ServiceSoap interface
- ServiceSoapChannel interface
- ServiceSoapClient partial class

I have been trying to consume the service with ServiceSoapClient like

```
ServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceSoapClient(); // or ServiceSoap client = new     ServiceSoapClient();
client.MethodName();
```

However using client seems not work because it doesn´t compile.
EDIT: It does compile but when I write client. it does't show any operation to use..

How can I consume this asmx web service?

Thanks!

Comment: `because it doesn´t compile.` -and I think the compilation error would help us!

Comment: Yes I forgot it, however if I write client. no operation is available to use..

Comment: can you post the WSDL of that service so we can verify if that isn't an issue on the server side?

Comment: Ok I have fix it. It was a little mistake when coding!